# Bad request 400 while searching an user in openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am trying to search an user in open fire.

```
public void searchUser(String username) {
        UserSearchManager userSearchManager = new UserSearchManager(
                xmppConnection);
        Form searchForm;
        try {

            searchForm = userSearchManager.getSearchForm("search."
                    + xmppConnection.getServiceName());

            Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
            answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);

            answerForm.setAnswer("search", username);

            org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData data = userSearchManager
                    .getSearchResults(answerForm,
                            "search." + xmppConnection.getServiceName());

            if (data.getRows() != null) {
                Iterator<Row> it = data.getRows();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = it.next();
                    Iterator<?> iterator = row.getValues("jid");
                    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String value = iterator.next().toString();
                        System.out.println(value);
                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

There are some similar thread so i followed them and added this provider manager before connection.

```
public void getProviderManager(ProviderManager providerManager) {

        // Private Data Storage
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",
                new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

        // Time
        try {
            providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",
                    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("TestClient",
                    "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
        }

        // Roster Exchange
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster",
                new RosterExchangeProvider());

        // Message Events
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",
                new MessageEventProvider());

        // Chat State
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("active",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("composing",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("paused",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("inactive",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("gone",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
                new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        // XHTML
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("html",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",
                new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

        // Group Chat Invitations
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",
                new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

        // Service Discovery # Items
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
                new DiscoverItemsProvider());

        // Service Discovery # Info
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
                new DiscoverInfoProvider());

        // Data Forms
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data",
                new DataFormProvider());

        // MUC User
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());

        // MUC Admin
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());

        // MUC Owner
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());

        // Delayed Delivery
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
                new DelayInformationProvider());

        // Version
        try {
            providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",
                    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // Not sure what's happening here.
        }

        // VCard
        providerManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                new VCardProvider());

        // Offline Message Requests
        providerManager.addIQProvider("offline",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
                new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());

        // Offline Message Indicator
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("offline",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
                new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());

        // Last Activity
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last",
                new LastActivity.Provider());

        // User Search
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search",
                new UserSearch.Provider());

        // SharedGroupsInfo
        providerManager.addIQProvider("sharedgroup",
                "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",
                new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

        // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("addresses",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/address",
                new MultipleAddressesProvider());

        // FileTransfer
        providerManager.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
                new StreamInitiationProvider());

        providerManager.addIQProvider("query",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
                new BytestreamsProvider());

        // Privacy
        providerManager.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy",
                new PrivacyProvider());
        providerManager.addIQProvider("command",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
        providerManager.addExtensionProvider("session-expired",
                "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
                new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());

    }
```

Still i am getting

```
12-07 01:14:58.027: W/System.err(1591): bad-request(400)
12-07 01:14:58.037: W/System.err(1591):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearch.getSearchForm(UserSearch.java:84)
12-07 01:14:58.037: W/System.err(1591):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearchManager.getSearchForm(UserSearchManager.java:73)
12-07 01:14:58.037: W/System.err(1591):     at com.afinity.core.chat.ChatManager.searchUser(ChatManager.java:107)
12-07 01:14:58.037: W/System.err(1591):     at com.afinity.chat.ui.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:19)
12-07 01:14:58.037: W/System.err(1591):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-07 01:14:58.047: W/System.err(1591):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by the following steps:

**step 1**:invoke the follow method *configure* before invoking XMPPConnection's connection.

**step 2**:invoke XMPPConnection's addConnectionListener and addPacketListener after invoking login(make sure XMPPConnection's isAuthenticated is true).

*The configure method:*

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",
            new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
    // Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",
                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster",
            new RosterExchangeProvider());
    // Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",
            new MessageEventProvider());
    // Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    // XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",
            new XHTMLExtensionProvider());
    // Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",
            new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
            new DiscoverItemsProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
            new DiscoverInfoProvider());
    // Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
    // MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user",
            new MUCUserProvider());
    // MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",
            new MUCAdminProvider());
    // MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",
            new MUCOwnerProvider());
    // Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
            new DelayInformationProvider());
    // Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",
                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Not sure what's happening here.
    }
    // VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
    // Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
    // Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
    // Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
    // User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
    // SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup",
            "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",
            new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
    // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/address",
            new MultipleAddressesProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());

}
```